# Link_to RoR with multiple alert box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

(New to RoR)I have a link_to in my erb file.

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', workflows_path+"/destroy/#{workflow.id}?folder=#{@folder_id}", :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete '#{workflow.name}'?"%>
```

This will prompt once asking the confirm message.

I want to prompt another alert box on Confirm(On pressing OK) asking "Do you want to delete sub-folders? " with a 'Yes' or 'No' option and pass it to my controller as a boolean(or any type)

(If they choose no, I would redirect the subfolders to parent directory)

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: why do use 'workflows_path' and than add a string to this?

Answer (score 0):

in order to have a double-confirmation you would need some javascript.

give your link a CSS class, like 'double-check-workflows'

then add a javascript to your page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a.double-check-workflows").on('click', function(){

    if confirm("first thing to ask"){
      target_url = $(this).attr("href")
      if confirm("second thing to ask"){
        target_url = target_url+"&your_other_param=1"
      }

      window.location = target_url

    }else{
      return false
    }

  })
})
```

remove the :confirm option from the link helper though cause the js wil handle that

edit

you should really use the routes helper to create the full url instead of adding params as a string as you posted

you could then add a 'delete_sub_folders' param that is default to false/0 and then replace it in the js with .replace() to set it to true/1 if second confirmation returns true

Comment: Thank you @Friends Systems. It makes sense. Just to know more, I was getting "Not a function" exception when I used the "on" method on jQuery. So I changed it to click method (  $("a.double-check-workflows").click(function()))
. The exception is gone. But the function still doesn't get called on link click.(I tried debugging it using alert statements).

Comment: Here is my link_method statement. 

<%= link_to 'Delete', workflows_path+"/destroy/#{workflow.id}?folder=#{@folder_id}", :class => 'double-check-workflows'%>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        alert(111);
        $("a.double-check-workflows").click(function(){
alert(222);
            if (confirm("first thing to ask")){
                target_url = $(this).attr("href")
                if (confirm("second thing to ask")){
                    target_url = target_url+"&your_other_param=1"
                }

                window.location = target_url

            }else{
                return false
            }

        })
    });
</script>

Comment: sorry for the format. Couldn't help it. here it always prompts 111 on page load. But 222 never gets prompted

Comment: can you check if $("a.double-check-workflows") returns the link element in the javascript console in the browser. it seems like the selector does not match any elements

Comment: It returned a null object. I changed it tojQuery("a.double-check-workflows") and it worked with below result. Still function doesn't get called on delete.


Object[a.double-check-workflows /.../o...folder=0, a.double-check-workflows /..../o...folder=0, a.double-check-workflows /..../o...folder=0, a.double-check-workflows /.../o...folder=0, a.double-check-workflows /.../o...folder=0, a.double-check-workflows /..../o...folder=0, a.double-check-workflows /..../o...folder=0]

Comment: which jquery version do you use?

Comment: jQuery.fn.jquery; => 1.4.2

Comment: Thanks for trying. Even I am using Firefox. Lemme try figuring it out. Will post back once I find the solution. Thanks again